# Problems with SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed

Over the past two days I have been experiencing various problems using SE sites - the first I noticed is that my chat wouldn't work even though I was logged in ("You need 20 reputation to talk here") when I was clearly logged in to SuperUser. Also on SU (as well as security.SE) I have not been able to upvote, add comments, or favorite questions.

I asked if anyone else on in the chat (once I was able) was having the same problems and the user `Carl B` said he was having the same problems if that helps to narrow down any possibilities. I have rebooted and cleared my browser cache as well, yet I am still not able to up/downvote / comment / favorite.

What could be causing this, could it be something I have done or is it on the SE side?

Edit: Also, the past two questions I have asked (this one and one on Security.SE) it has asked me to enter in a captcha. Not sure if that's relevant, but I figured I would add this. I can also not view up/down votes on questions, and when I click the StackExchange drop-down menu in the upper left it takes me to stackexchange.com

---

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Yiz.png) is what the error console shows 
[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Sathya it seems to be browser specific, it works fine in Chrome (as well as FF)

Comment: hit F12, click on Console & refresh the page. Post a screenshot the error console here

Comment: looks like stub.js is not loaded properly, [try doing a hard refresh](http://superuser.com/q/81182/4377)

Comment: all your problems are symptom of js files not being loaded properly, and seems localized to you..

Comment: IE is not a real browser :P /snark.  That aside, does http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=687a872fb474 open properly? or is it cut half way off? Try visiting that link & do a hard refresh few times

Comment: =p This is the result, with a hard refresh: http://i.imgur.com/osmIL8o.png

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek 9.0.8112.16421, update version 9.0.15 (KB2817183)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [JavaScript on whole site is broken in IE (9 or less) because of stub.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176467/javascript-on-whole-site-is-broken-in-ie-9-or-less-because-of-stub-js):

> We are trying to block a scraper that is scraping against our terms & conditions.
>
> This bug was an unforeseen consequence of trying to ban them client side - not realizing that atob is not supported by IE 7/8/9 (and 10 in 7/8/9 mode).
>
> I am reverting the change and deploying as we speak.

Things should be back to normal soon-ish.